# What are the consequences of dying on foot?

Tags: elite-dangerous-odyssey

When your ship is destroyed in the base game, you have to pay to replace it. So before, death had a very obvious cost since it was listed in your ship status screen.

However, in Elite Dangerous: Odyssey, they have introduced infantry combat, which means you can die without destroying a vehicle. What are the consequences of dying on foot?

Comment: [about to make a joke about dying via other methods of travel]... oh.

Comment: You will be teleported to the nearest medical facility and revived, but I assume you specifically want to know what things you will lose access to or have to rebuy and such right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main consequence is wasted time. If you die on foot, you are respawned back to your ship, that gets sent in orbit. If your ship is not nearby, like you took Apex to land on the planet, you respawn at a station. You then have to proceed to land on the planet again to proceed with what you were doing.

Additional items

- The mission you were working on is marked as failure.
- You lose any loot that was on your person

If you were just on a conflict zone and die during the "match", it's just a very long delay to get back into the action.

Comment: You also lose any organic data, codex discovery claims and intel packages. Just had this happen when I spontaneously died because I touched an allies ship when it started its engines, the ship did not even move.